# SQL Join gives 30 same results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using a join to get messages from two tables

**Table Messages:** ID, Sender, Receiver, Message, Password

**Table OwnMessages:** ID, Sender, Receiver, Message, Password

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Messages.ID) as F_id, 
               Messages.Message as F_message, 
               Messages.Password as F_password, 
               Messages.Receiver as F_receiver, 
               OwnMessages.ID as O_id, 
               OwnMessages.Message as O_message, 
               OwnMessages.Password as O_password, 
               OwnMessages.Sender as O_sender
FROM Messages
JOIN OwnMessages on Messages.Receiver = OwnMessages.Sender
WHERE Messages.Receiver = 8 AND OwnMessages.Sender = 8
```

Everything from the table Messages displays correctly but from the table OwnMessages I get the first row 30 times. Any ideas?

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. It applies to **all** columns of the `select` list.

Comment: I also tried it without the distinct and got the exact same results

Comment: Maybe there are columns in OwnMessages with different values (not selected here)?

Comment: If you add some sample table data and current result and wanted result, it will be much easier to help you!

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question.  Start with sample data and the results that you want to achieve.  Your query works and does *exactly* what it is designed to do.  You simply have not conveyed what you are really trying to do.  A non-working query often doesn't convey that information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
               Messages.ID as F_id, 
               Messages.Message as F_message, 
               Messages.Password as F_password, 
               Messages.Receiver as F_receiver, 
               OwnMessages.ID as O_id, 
               OwnMessages.Message as O_message, 
               OwnMessages.Password as O_password, 
               OwnMessages.Sender as O_sender
FROM Messages
INNER JOIN OwnMessages on Messages.Receiver = OwnMessages.Sender
WHERE Messages.Receiver = 8 AND OwnMessages.Sender = 8
```

or

```
SELECT             Messages.ID as F_id, 
                   Messages.Message as F_message, 
                   Messages.Password as F_password, 
                   Messages.Receiver as F_receiver, 
                   OwnMessages.ID as O_id, 
                   OwnMessages.Message as O_message, 
                   OwnMessages.Password as O_password, 
                   OwnMessages.Sender as O_sender
    FROM Messages
    INNER JOIN OwnMessages on Messages.Receiver = OwnMessages.Sender
    WHERE Messages.Receiver = 8 AND OwnMessages.Sender = 8
    GROUP BY Messages.ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```